# calling acronym in nomenclature package

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

just like in acronym package we can call the acronym by \ac and glossary by \gls,can someone please guide me how to call acronym while using the package nomenclature

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index,custommargin]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature
```

here are commands i used to define the acronyms.(z is for acronym definition)

```
\nomenclature[Z]{$WDM$}{Wavelength Division Multiplexing} 
\nomenclature[Z]{$EDFA$}{Erbium Doped Fiber Amplifiers}
```

i don't know how to call them after the definition if they are appearing in  later sections also.

Comment: Welcome! `nomencl` isn't developed for such a usage. It's a simple method to produce a nomenclature. Why don't you use `glossaries`?

Comment: Marco, as one of the authors of `nomencl`, I disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
\nomenclature{WDM}{Wavelength Division Multiplexing} 
\nomenclature{EDFA}{Erbium Doped Fiber Amplifiers}
```

Note the absence of dollar signs: this is not math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norefeq]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abbreviations}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
In the text we will discuss WDM and EDFA.
\nomenclature{WDM}{Wavelength Division Multiplexing}%
\nomenclature{DFA}{Erbium Doped Fiber Amplifiers}%

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Boris, can you please confirm me if  this package is only for list ?
actually i want to use it such that for the first usage the name should be complete but for the subsequent use it should be replaced by the acronym..thanks

Comment: Yes, this package makes lists of items, optionally accompanied by the reference to the page or equation where the item was first mentioned